# Why everything looks messed up when I'm not locked to the camera?

Tags: modeling, camera, geometry, error

Blender newbie here. I've been working on a background for quite some time, I stopped working on it for a couple of weeks and last time I was on the file everything was ok but when I opened it today I found this issue.

When the camera is locked to view everything looks fine.
[image]

But when I uncheck "Lock camera to view" and move around everything gets messed up

[image]

It seems to be a problem with this file only, I opened other files and they were just fine. I tried opening and closing this file again and rebooting the computer but it did nothing.

Also this file is kinda heavy so when I go into render preview my computer struggles but when I opened it today even in solid mode my computer was kinda slow.

I don't know if maybe an output or render setting is messed up but that doesn't make sense to me because the last time I worked on this file everything was alright and today I didn't change anything.

[image]

I'm using Blender 3.2.1 on windows 10 (22H2) 64 bit

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Maybe a clipping issue? In the N panel > View > View > Clip Start and End values

Comment: @moonboots Yes, I would agree. The clipping range in the viewport is much too high. It should be set to something more reasonable like _Clip Start_ at 0.01 or 0.1 and _End_ 10000 or 1000, depending on what is actually needed.

Comment: Yes! It seems it was the clipping, I changed it to the values Gordon said and now it's working properly. Thank you, guys!